# How can I get user's logged Id from SecurityContextHolder using Spring Social?

Tags: spring, spring-security

So, how can I get the user's id from a current logged user from any social providers?
Well I know I can build a custom SocialUser, the same I do for User, but in the case there is no getter on SocialUserDetails and the method I got just accepts userDetails, instead of a normal "Person" entity.

```
public class SocialUsersDetailServiceImpl implements SocialUserDetailsService {


    private UserDetailsService service;

    public SocialUsersDetailServiceImpl(UserDetailsService service) {
        this.service = service;
    }

    @Override
    public CSocialUserDetails loadUserByUserId(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {
        UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) service.loadUserByUsername(username);
        return new CustomSocialUser(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getPassword(), userDetails.getAuthorities(), userDetails.getUserIdentifier()??);

    }
}
```

But there is no ".getUserIdentifier()" method on UserDetails, there is some workaround for this?

The way I do for User:

```
@Service
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements CUserDetailsService {

   @Resource
   private PersonRepository respository;

    @Override
    public CUserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Person p = repository.findByUsername(username);
        return new CUser(p.getUsername(), p.getPassword(), p.grantedAuthorities(), p.getIdPerson());
    }
}
```

and the CUser:

```
public class CUser extends User{


    private Number identifier;

    public CUser(String username, String password, Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities, Number identifier) {
        super(username, password, authorities);
        this.identifier = identifier;

    }


    public Number getUserIdentifier() {
        return identifier;
    }

}
```